# Symfony: Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'security' (T_STRING), expecting ']'

Tags: php, symfony

I am working with Symfony, and I am trying to include a service using services.yml, and I am getting this error:

Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'security' (T_STRING), expecting ']'

Everything seems fine. I checked the service I created, and there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: self answering is great .. but not for a syntax error

Comment: @rtfm Probably not the best duplicate since the syntax error was in YAML not PHP. I voted to close for the "simple typographical error" reason

Comment: Next time try a little before asking here. And if you really need to ask, put a piece of code, otherwise you are asking us to do magic.

Comment: @Paulpro fair call. but it is a php error message

Answer (score -1):

The problem was inside the services.yml file itself:

```
    activity_listener\:
          class: AppBundle\Listener\ActivityListener
          arguments: 
                 ['@security.token_storage']
```

It is hard to notice at first. I put a \ at the end of activity_listener, and when that became part of PHP, it neutralized the ' that followed.